# Hibernate : Multitenancy by schema AND by column

Tags: hibernate, multi-tenant

We already have an app implementing multitenancy by schema with Hibernate.

Is it possible to add, in top of that, a "versioning" of my data model by adding a discriminating column ?

i.e. I start working on my data, and every data is stored in DB with a version "1" stored in discriminating column.
Then, I think this version of my data is ready, I push a button, and now can start working on a version "2".

The idea is that I must be able to load a specific version of my data in my app and work on it. I muse be able to switch between multiple versions. I'd like to know if it's possible to benefit from Hibernate multitenancy abilities to implement this.

We have a big existing code base and data model, so "manually" handling this is something I'd rather avoid if possible (i.e. altering all my requests / entities).
There's quite a lot of data and complex queries too, so performance does matter here.

Comment: What do you mean by "versioning"?

Comment: Details added, thanks for your question.

Answer (score 0):

All you seem to want is a way to distinguish between published/draft, so why not just introduce a `boolean draft` flag on your entities and enable a Hibernate filter, depending on your use case, that either adds `draft = true` or `draft = false`. Also see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter-entity-query-example

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. We have a complex data model (100+ tables) and an existing code base. Ideally, I don't want to update all my queries. 
Also, I must handle several versions, not just a draft state.
And @Filter won't benefit from Hibernate 2d level cache (correct me if I'm wrong please), whereas multitenancy mechanism will. Updating my question to reflect those points.

Comment: Filters are obviously considered when caching. You also don't have to update all your queries, just the places where you are creating a `Session`/`EntityManager`. There you inject whatever thing you want to use to decide which state to filter on and enable the respective filter. You just define the filters with the same name on entity classes and enable them.